# C# Windows Forms Application | Cookie Clicker

Tags: c#

Im trying to make a cookie maker!
it works great and all but every time i click on the cookie, it takes it about 2 clicks to add just one to the cookie count. I want to make the counting system go faster, since if i click 2 times a second, it will only count as one atm...

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
namespace FormalCookie
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int cnum = 0;        
        int add = 1;


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            label1.Text = ("Price For Mouse:" + " 50");
            textBox1.Text = ("Cookies:" + " " + cnum);
            mouse.Enabled = false;

            for (int i = 0; i< add; i++)
            { 
                if (add > 1 && add % 2 == 0)
                {
                    cnum += 1 * add;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Mouse
            if (cnum >= add * add * 50)
            {
                cnum -= (add * 100);
                add+=2;
            }


        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Restart();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (cnum >= (add * add * 50))
            {
                mouse.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                mouse.Enabled = false;
            }

            cnum += (add * add);
            textBox1.Text = ("Cookies:" + " " + cnum);

            label1.Text = ("Price For Mouse:" + " " + (add * add * 50));
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, i think it has something to do with the MouseClick/Click events. The current event is just the normal Click one. Do i need to change this? also, This line (pictureBox1_Click) refers to the cookie Picture.

Comment: Try `MouseLeftButtonDown` event instead of `Click`.